# Jenkins REST API to retrieve completed job info

Tags: rest, jenkins

I am simply trying to retrieve completed job info including the job result and have looked at many articles and still I can't get the completed job info.  The latest url I tried is as follows:

```
https://<myjenkinsserver>/jenkins/<jenkinsinstancename>/api/json/&pretty=true&depth=3&tree=builds[actions[parameters[name,value]],number,result,building]
```

but still I get nothing that looks at all like what I am looking for.  Everything I am seeing appears to be the static jobs defined, not the completed results of the jobs because there is no job number in the results that I see which has to be there if I want to query the results of a completed job!

Here is a snippet of what I get back:

```
{"_class":"hudson.model.Hudson","assignedLabels":[{"name":"docker"},{"name":"master"}],"mode":"EXCLUSIVE","nodeDescription":"the master Jenkins node","nodeName":"","numExecutors":4,"description":null,
"jobs":[{"_class":"hudson.model.FreeStyleProject","name":"build_GBO","url":"https://<jenkinsserver>/jenkins/<jenkinsinstance>/job/API_build_GBO/","color":"disabled"},...
```

Thoughts?

Thanks,
Don Bouchard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier to write URL for per job basis.
For the URL as follows:

```
http://jenkinsinstance:9090/job/JOB_NAME/api/json?tree=builds[number,result,duration,url,actions[parameters[name,value]]]
```

The output will be as follows:
You get

1. Build
2. Actions or Parameters for the build.
3. duration for which the build executed.
4. Build Number
5. Build Results Pass or Fail
6. url

[image: Build Results]

Edit:
To get all jobs all results at the root level the url is

```
http://jenkinsinstance/api/json?tree=jobs[name,url,builds[number,result,duration,url]]
```

This will list all the jobs at root level. If you have folders as highlighted you can parse into those urls.
[image: all results]

Comment: Thanks for this info, but I was hoping (and perhaps this is as good as it's gonna get) to get a complete list of all jobs and their results without having to know in advance the job names.  Is this not possible?

Comment: You can paass the same URL but at the root level. But there is warning that the list would be very very long.  I updated the answer to reflect the url.